# PHP same Session user login

Tags: php, session, authentication

I searched but I can't find solution for me.

I have login.php file which redirect user to another page in my case `theme.php?id=".$row['log_name']."`.

```
<?php

include ('conn.php');

//Uzivatelsky vstup
$log_meno = mysqli_real_escape_string ($Conn, $_POST['login_name']);
$cmp_heslo = sha1($_POST['login_password']);  

$sql = "SELECT id, cmp_heslo, log_meno FROM firmy WHERE log_meno='$log_meno'";
$result = mysqli_query($Conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if ($cmp_heslo == $row[cmp_heslo])
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged'] = 'yes';
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='comp_page/theme.php?id=".$row['log_name']."';</script>";                
}
else
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='bad_login.php';</script>";
}     
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}  

mysqli_close($Conn);

 ?>
```

**theme.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged'] != 'yes' )
    die("You have to sign in first!");

?>
```

In MySQL I have two users

- `kuki` with pass `kuki`
- `cuki` with pass `cuki`

My question is when I am signed in as kuki I have in address bar:

> http://localhost/comp_page/theme.php?id=kuki

But I need when I rewrite in address bar `kuki` to `cuki` to change to access denied becuase now only address bar changed but page is same. I am new to PHP.

Comment: First you have access denied message?

Comment: No I need to show access denied message or something similary message when someone try rewrite in address bar kuki to cuki. Because Now it looks when i sign in as kuki i can simply rewrite adressbar and i am signed as cuki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from having this in your session

> $_SESSION['logged'] = 'yes';

I suggest you need to add also something like this,

> $_SESSION['id'] = $row['log_name'];

and in your theme.php

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged'] != 'yes' ) {
    die("You have to sign in first!");
} else {
 if ($_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
  // do somthing
 } else {
  echo "Access Denied!";
 }
}
```

having this URL

> http://localhost/comp_page/theme.php?id=kuki

meaning you are sending data, the `id` to the server with the `get` method. This `$_GET['id']` catch that data and will have a value either `kuki` or `cuki` from the URI `theme.php?id=kuki` or `theme.php?id=cuki`.

This condition `if ($_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id'])` will determine if the value of id is the same with the user store in the session.

Comment: Thank you very much Fil that is exactly what I need. :)

Comment: If you feel this help please check it